# MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'my_cursor'

Tags: mysql, attributes

Im new to mysql. installed gitbash, sublime text and mysql. pip3 working. able to import mysql.connector.
Im trying to create a database called mydb
Problem is, Im getting attribute error: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'my_cursor'

> python database.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "database.py", line 10, in 
> my_cursor = mydb.my_cursor()
> AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'my_cursor''

Comment: Please use the title to communicate the nature of your problem. Stay focused on that. People will want to look at titles and pick out things they can help with, and "Hi, I'm creating a database" is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which import you are using and did you used some at all but you should try to use this:

```
import MySQLdb
```

Also i think you need to use cursor() instead of my_cursor(). Question is not explained well, i don't have source code so i cannot be precise.

Comment: i doubt  that my_cursor is part of that mibrary

Comment: I had used import mysql.connectorModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: You need to install it with pip. Also find some documentation for that library before using it.